# Can anyone help me in this design problem?

Tags: css

I'm working on a website for kids to learn maths and physics :)
There are two problems I couldn't find the solution to :

1. I want to move the operations fieldset to inside  Basic math Operations.
2. I want to make all titles of fieldsets on the same line and make all fieldsets the same size.
   Thanks for your patience
   This is my code :
   Ps: I'm not a professional programmer I'm just a math teacher and not an English native speaker sorry if there is an error in my language.

```js
function clickSolve()
{
    let temp=document.getElementsByName("op");
    let op=getOp(temp);
    let num1= parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value) ;
    let num2=parseInt( document.getElementById("num2").value);
    let num3=myOperation(num1,num2,op);
    document.getElementById("result").innerText=num3;
}
function getOp(oparr)
{ // Get wich radio button is checked
   for(let i=0;i<oparr.length;i++)
   {
       if(oparr[i].checked)
       {
            return oparr[i].value;
       }
   }
}
function myOperation(num1,num2,op)
{
    switch(op){
        case "+":
            return num1+num2;
        case "-":
            return num1-num2;
        case "*":
            return num1*num2;
        case "/":
            return num1/num2;
    }
}
function getFactirial(){
    let num=document.getElementById("factNumber").value;
    document.getElementById("factResult").innerText=factorial(num);
}
function getFibonacci(){
    let num=document.getElementById("fibonacciNumber").value;
    document.getElementById("fibResult").innerText=fibonacci(num);
}
function factorial(x) {
// find the factorial of a number
    // if number is 0
    if (x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    // if number is positive
    else {
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }
} 
function fibonacci(x)
{
    // find the fibonacci of a number
    if(x<=1){
        return x;
    }
    else{
        return fibonacci(x-1)+fibonacci(x-2);
    }
}
let slider = document.getElementById("temperatureValue");
let output = document.getElementById("tValue");
let fahrenheitVar=0;
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value
// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  fahrenheitVar=((this.value/5)*9)+32;
  document.getElementById("fahrenheitVal").innerText=parseInt(fahrenheitVar);
}

function getRndInteger(min, max) 
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:  #1E0555;
  font-family: cursive;
}
.div_style {
  background-color:#F0DB4F;
  align-content: center;
  font-size: large;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tableStyle {
  width: fit-content;
  align-content: center;
}

.fieldsetStyle{
 color: #F0DB4F;
 border: 2px solid #F0DB4F;
 
 height: 50%;
}
.textbox1 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.textbox2 {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-left: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}
.liststyle {
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
}
.lableStyle{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>English site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="tableStyle">
      <tr class="trStyle">
        <td>
          <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
            <legend>Basic math Operations</legend>
            <div class="div_style" id="div_back">
              <label class="lableStyle" for="num1">First Number:</label>
              <input class="textbox1" type="text" id="num1" /><br />
              <label class="lableStyle" for="num2">Second Number:</label>
              <input class="textbox2" type="text" id="num2" /><br />
              <label class="lableStyle" for="">Result: </label>
              <label class="lableStyle" for="" id="result"></label>
              <br /><br />
              <button class="btn" onclick="clickSolve();">Calc</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </td>
        <td>
          <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
            <legend>Operations</legend>
            <div class="div_style">
              <li class="liststyle">
                <input type="radio" name="op" value="+" checked /> +
              </li>
              <li class="liststyle">
                <input type="radio" name="op" value="-" /> -
              </li>
              <li class="liststyle">
                <input type="radio" name="op" value="*" /> *
              </li>
              <li class="liststyle">
                <input type="radio" name="op" value="/" /> /
              </li>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </td>
        <td>
          <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
            <legend>Find factorial</legend>
            <div class="div_style">
              <label class="lableStyle" for="">Number:</label>
              <input type="number" id="factNumber" min="0" max="7" />
              <br />
              <label class="lableStyle" for="">Factorial is:</label>
              <label class="lableStyle" id="factResult" for="">?</label><br />
              <button class="btn" onclick="getFactirial();">Calc</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </td>
        <td>
          <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
            <legend>Find fibonacci</legend>
            <div class="div_style">
              <label for="" class="lableStyle">Number:</label>
              <input type="number" id="fibonacciNumber" min="0" max="9" /><br />
              <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fibonacci is:</label>
              <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fibResult">?</label><br />
              <button class="btn" onclick="getFibonacci();">Calc</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </td>
        <td>
          <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
            <legend>Temperature converter</legend>
            <div class="div_style">
              <label for="" class="lableStyle">Temperature celsius:</label>
              <input
                type="range"
                id="temperatureValue"
                min="0"
                max="100"
                step="1"
              />
              <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="tValue">0</label><br />
              <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fahrenheit:</label>
              <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fahrenheitVal">?</label>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="jsfuctions.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, you should not use `table` in HTML for layout.

Comment: How to make all fieldsets the same size?

Comment: It's hard to do with tables, If you say I will make a better design...

Comment: Manas thanks again,just tell me what should I do, if I removed the table how can i divide the page to blocks in same size

Comment: Using new technologies like `flexbox` and `cssgrid`

Comment: Wait for some time I will share a better design with you, using Bootstrap...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230474/discussion-between-stefano-and-manas-khandelwal).

Comment: Have you left the chat?

Comment: Check this out: https://stefanomath.netlify.app/

Comment: For further chat let's use some other means of chat, like discord or something... And plz reply here 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
    background-color: #1E0555;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.div_style {
    background-color: #F0DB4F;
    align-content: center;
    font-size: large;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.tableStyle {
    width: fit-content;
}

.fieldsetStyle {
    color: #F0DB4F;
    border: 2px solid #F0DB4F;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
}

.textbox1 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.textbox2 {
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: cursive;
    margin-left: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
}

.liststyle {
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}

.lableStyle {
    color: black;
}

tbody {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableStyle">
        <tr class="trStyle">
            <td>
                <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
                    <legend>Basic math Operations</legend>
                    <div class="div_style" id="div_back">
                        <label class="lableStyle" for="num1">First Number:</label>
                        <input class="textbox1" type="text" id="num1" /><br />
                        <label class="lableStyle" for="num2">Second Number:</label>
                        <input class="textbox2" type="text" id="num2" /><br />
                        <label class="lableStyle" for="">Result: </label>
                        <label class="lableStyle" for="" id="result"></label>
                        <br /><br />
                        <button class="btn" onclick="clickSolve();">Calc</button>
                    </div>
                    <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
                        <legend>Operations</legend>
                        <div class="div_style">
                            <li class="liststyle">
                                <input type="radio" name="op" value="+" checked /> +
                            </li>
                            <li class="liststyle">
                                <input type="radio" name="op" value="-" /> -
                            </li>
                            <li class="liststyle">
                                <input type="radio" name="op" value="*" /> *
                            </li>
                            <li class="liststyle">
                                <input type="radio" name="op" value="/" /> /
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
                    <legend>Find factorial</legend>
                    <div class="div_style">
                        <label class="lableStyle" for="">Number:</label>
                        <input type="number" id="factNumber" min="0" max="7" />
                        <br />
                        <label class="lableStyle" for="">Factorial is:</label>
                        <label class="lableStyle" id="factResult" for="">?</label><br />
                        <button class="btn" onclick="getFactirial();">Calc</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
                    <legend>Find fibonacci</legend>
                    <div class="div_style">
                        <label for="" class="lableStyle">Number:</label>
                        <input type="number" id="fibonacciNumber" min="0" max="9" /><br />
                        <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fibonacci is:</label>
                        <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fibResult">?</label><br />
                        <button class="btn" onclick="getFibonacci();">Calc</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
                    <legend>Temperature converter</legend>
                    <div class="div_style">
                        <label for="" class="lableStyle">Temperature celsius:</label>
                        <input type="range" id="temperatureValue" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
                        <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="tValue">0</label><br />
                        <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fahrenheit:</label>
                        <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fahrenheitVal">?</label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

If you inspect the **tbody**, you will see a default style `vertical-align` set to **center**.
If you change it to **top**, your items will align to the top.

For the operations, you can **move the fieldset "operations" to inside the first fieldset "Basic math Operations"**, so it sits inside it. Operations fieldset will show by default on the bottom. To show it on the right side you can for example use `display:flex` on class **.fieldsetStyle** and add `width: 100%` to the **.div_style** class (so it's not smaller).
The provided code has the mentioned changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to move the operations fieldset to inside Basic math Operations.*

To get the `Operations` inside `Basic math Operations`. Move the `Operations`'
`<fieldset>` inside the `Basic math Operations` `<fieldset>`.

To get them side by side use `flexbox`:

Add this class `basicMathsFieldset` to the `Basic math Operations` `<fieldset>`.

```
.basicMathsFieldset {
    display: flex;
}
```

> *I want to make all titles of fieldsets on the same line and make all fieldsets the same size.*

To get `<td>` on the same line, use `vertical-align: top;`, Like this:

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

---

#### Final Code:

```js
function clickSolve() {
  let temp = document.getElementsByName("op");
  let op = getOp(temp);
  let num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  let num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  let num3 = myOperation(num1, num2, op);
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = num3;
}

function getOp(oparr) {
  // Get wich radio button is checked
  for (let i = 0; i < oparr.length; i++) {
    if (oparr[i].checked) {
      return oparr[i].value;
    }
  }
}

function myOperation(num1, num2, op) {
  switch (op) {
    case "+":
      return num1 + num2;
    case "-":
      return num1 - num2;
    case "*":
      return num1 * num2;
    case "/":
      return num1 / num2;
  }
}

function getFactirial() {
  let num = document.getElementById("factNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("factResult").innerText = factorial(num);
}

function getFibonacci() {
  let num = document.getElementById("fibonacciNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("fibResult").innerText = fibonacci(num);
}

function factorial(x) {
  // find the factorial of a number
  // if number is 0
  if (x == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  // if number is positive
  else {
    return x * factorial(x - 1);
  }
}

function fibonacci(x) {
  // find the fibonacci of a number
  if (x <= 1) {
    return x;
  } else {
    return fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2);
  }
}
let slider = document.getElementById("temperatureValue");
let output = document.getElementById("tValue");
let fahrenheitVar = 0;
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value
// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  fahrenheitVar = (this.value / 5) * 9 + 32;
  document.getElementById("fahrenheitVal").innerText = parseInt(fahrenheitVar);
};

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #1e0555;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.div_style {
    background-color: #f0db4f;
    align-content: center;
    font-size: large;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.tableStyle {
    width: fit-content;
    align-content: center;
}

.fieldsetStyle {
    color: #f0db4f;
    border: 2px solid #f0db4f;
    height: 50%;
}

.textbox1 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.textbox2 {
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: cursive;
    margin-left: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
}

.liststyle {
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}

.lableStyle {
    color: black;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.basicMathsFieldset {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableStyle">
    <tr class="trStyle">
        <td>
            <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle basicMathsFieldset">
                <legend>Basic math Operations</legend>
                <div class="div_style" id="div_back">
                    <label class="lableStyle" for="num1">First Number:</label>
                    <input class="textbox1" type="text" id="num1" />
                    <br />
                    <label class="lableStyle" for="num2">Second Number:</label>
                    <input class="textbox2" type="text" id="num2" />
                    <br />
                    <label class="lableStyle" for="">Result:</label>
                    <label class="lableStyle" for="" id="result"></label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <button class="btn" onclick="clickSolve();">Calc</button>
                </div>

                <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
                    <legend>Operations</legend>
                    <div class="div_style">
                        <li class="liststyle">
                            <input type="radio" name="op" value="+" checked />
                            +
                        </li>
                        <li class="liststyle">
                            <input type="radio" name="op" value="-" />
                            -
                        </li>
                        <li class="liststyle">
                            <input type="radio" name="op" value="*" />
                            *
                        </li>
                        <li class="liststyle">
                            <input type="radio" name="op" value="/" />
                            /
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>

        </td>
        <td>
            <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
                <legend>Find factorial</legend>
                <div class="div_style">
                    <label class="lableStyle" for="">Number:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="factNumber" min="0" max="7" />
                    <br />
                    <label class="lableStyle" for="">Factorial is:</label>
                    <label class="lableStyle" id="factResult" for="">?</label>
                    <br />
                    <button class="btn" onclick="getFactirial();">Calc</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
        <td>
            <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
                <legend>Find fibonacci</legend>
                <div class="div_style">
                    <label for="" class="lableStyle">Number:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="fibonacciNumber" min="0" max="9" />
                    <br />
                    <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fibonacci is:</label>
                    <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fibResult">?</label>
                    <br />
                    <button class="btn" onclick="getFibonacci();">Calc</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
        <td>
            <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
                <legend>Temperature converter</legend>
                <div class="div_style">
                    <label for="" class="lableStyle">Temperature celsius:</label>
                    <input type="range" id="temperatureValue" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
                    <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="tValue">0</label>
                    <br />
                    <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fahrenheit:</label>
                    <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fahrenheitVal">?</label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

[Check it in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/oNBLexx)

Answer (score 0):

I added `valign="top"` to some `<td>`

```js
function clickSolve() {
  let temp = document.getElementsByName("op");
  let op = getOp(temp);
  let num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  let num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  let num3 = myOperation(num1, num2, op);
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = num3;
}

function getOp(oparr) { // Get wich radio button is checked
  for (let i = 0; i < oparr.length; i++) {
    if (oparr[i].checked) {
      return oparr[i].value;
    }
  }
}

function myOperation(num1, num2, op) {
  switch (op) {
    case "+":
      return num1 + num2;
    case "-":
      return num1 - num2;
    case "*":
      return num1 * num2;
    case "/":
      return num1 / num2;
  }
}

function getFactirial() {
  let num = document.getElementById("factNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("factResult").innerText = factorial(num);
}

function getFibonacci() {
  let num = document.getElementById("fibonacciNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("fibResult").innerText = fibonacci(num);
}

function factorial(x) {
  // find the factorial of a number
  // if number is 0
  if (x == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  // if number is positive
  else {
    return x * factorial(x - 1);
  }
}

function fibonacci(x) {
  // find the fibonacci of a number
  if (x <= 1) {
    return x;
  } else {
    return fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2);
  }
}
let slider = document.getElementById("temperatureValue");
let output = document.getElementById("tValue");
let fahrenheitVar = 0;
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value
// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  fahrenheitVar = ((this.value / 5) * 9) + 32;
  document.getElementById("fahrenheitVal").innerText = parseInt(fahrenheitVar);
}

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #1E0555;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.div_style {
  background-color: #F0DB4F;
  font-size: large;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.tableStyle {
  width: fit-content;
}

.fieldsetStyle {
  color: #F0DB4F;
  border: 2px solid #F0DB4F;
}

.textbox1 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.textbox2 {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-left: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}

.liststyle {
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
}

.lableStyle {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>English site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <table class="tableStyle">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
          <legend>Basic math Operations</legend>
          <table class="div_style">
            <tr>
              <td>



                <label class="lableStyle" for="num1">First Number:</label>
                <input class="textbox1" type="text" id="num1" /><br />
                <label class="lableStyle" for="num2">Second Number:</label>
                <input class="textbox2" type="text" id="num2" /><br />
                <label class="lableStyle" for="">Result: </label>
                <label class="lableStyle" for="" id="result"></label>
                <br /><br />
                <button class="btn" onclick="clickSolve();">Calc</button>



              </td>
              <td valign="top">
                <label class="lableStyle" for="">Operation : </label>
                <li class="liststyle">
                  <input type="radio" name="op" value="+" checked /> +
                </li>
                <li class="liststyle">
                  <input type="radio" name="op" value="-" /> -
                </li>
                <li class="liststyle">
                  <input type="radio" name="op" value="*" /> *
                </li>
                <li class="liststyle">
                  <input type="radio" name="op" value="/" /> /
                </li>
        </fieldset>
        </td>

        </tr>
        </table>

      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
          <legend>Find factorial</legend>
          <div class="div_style">
            <label class="lableStyle" for="">Number:</label>
            <input type="number" id="factNumber" min="0" max="7" />
            <br />
            <label class="lableStyle" for="">Factorial is:</label>
            <label class="lableStyle" id="factResult" for="">?</label><br />
            <button class="btn" onclick="getFactirial();">Calc</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
          <legend>Find fibonacci</legend>
          <div class="div_style">
            <label for="" class="lableStyle">Number:</label>
            <input type="number" id="fibonacciNumber" min="0" max="9" /><br />
            <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fibonacci is:</label>
            <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fibResult">?</label><br />
            <button class="btn" onclick="getFibonacci();">Calc</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
          <legend>Temperature converter</legend>
          <div class="div_style">
            <label for="" class="lableStyle">Temperature celsius:</label>
            <input type="range" id="temperatureValue" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
            <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="tValue">0</label><br />
            <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fahrenheit:</label>
            <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fahrenheitVal">?</label>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="jsfuctions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've made some changes in your HTML, you don't need a table do that. See if it's what you're looking for.

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
      <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
        <legend>Basic math Operations</legend>
        <div class="basics div_style">
          <div id="div_back">
            <label class="lableStyle" for="num1">First Number:</label>
            <input class="textbox1" type="text" id="num1" /><br />
            <label class="lableStyle" for="num2">Second Number:</label>
            <input class="textbox2" type="text" id="num2" /><br />
            <label class="lableStyle" for="">Result: </label>
            <label class="lableStyle" for="" id="result"></label>
            <br /><br />
            <button class="btn" onclick="clickSolve();">Calc</button>
          </div>
          <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle fieldsetStyle--blue">
            <legend>Operations</legend>
            <div class="div_style">
              <li class="liststyle">
                <input type="radio" name="op" value="+" checked /> +
              </li>
              <li class="liststyle">
                <input type="radio" name="op" value="-" /> -
              </li>
              <li class="liststyle">
                <input type="radio" name="op" value="*" /> *
              </li>
              <li class="liststyle">
                <input type="radio" name="op" value="/" /> /
              </li>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
        <legend>Find factorial</legend>
        <div class="div_style">
          <label class="lableStyle" for="">Number:</label>
          <input type="number" id="factNumber" min="0" max="7" />
          <br />
          <label class="lableStyle" for="">Factorial is:</label>
          <label class="lableStyle" id="factResult" for="">?</label><br />
          <button class="btn" onclick="getFactirial();">Calc</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
        <legend>Find fibonacci</legend>
        <div class="div_style">
          <label for="" class="lableStyle">Number:</label>
          <input type="number" id="fibonacciNumber" min="0" max="9" /><br />
          <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fibonacci is:</label>
          <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fibResult">?</label><br />
          <button class="btn" onclick="getFibonacci();">Calc</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
        <legend>Temperature converter</legend>
        <div class="div_style">
          <label for="" class="lableStyle">Temperature celsius:</label>
          <input
            type="range"
            id="temperatureValue"
            min="0"
            max="100"
            step="1"
          />
          <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="tValue">0</label><br />
          <label for="" class="lableStyle">Fahrenheit:</label>
          <label for="" class="lableStyle" id="fahrenheitVal">?</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And some changes to your CSS.

```
body {
  background-color: #1e0555;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.basics {
  display: flex;
}

.div_style {
  background-color: #f0db4f;
  font-size: large;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.fieldsetStyle {
  color: #f0db4f;
  border: 2px solid #f0db4f;
}

.fieldsetStyle--blue {
  color: #1e0555;
  border: 2px solid #1e0555;
}

.textbox1 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.textbox2 {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-left: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}

.liststyle {
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
}

.lableStyle {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir I really appreciate your help, but how to make all fieldsets the same size?